# best way (and fast) to log http request get/post parameters

Tags: java, httprequest

I'm developing an Web JEE5 Application, I need to log the http post and get parameters, What is the best way?

At the beginning I tried with HttpRequest->getQueryString, but it doesn't work with post parameters, 
then I wrote a code  that uses HttpRequest->getParameterMap  (see below)

```
Map<String,String[]> parametersName=theRequest.getParameterMap();

int count=0;

for (String paramName : parametersName.keySet()) {
String[] paramValues=parametersName.get(paramName);
   if(count>0)
       allParameter.append("&");

   allParameter.append(paramName);
   allParameter.append("=");
   for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
       allParameter.append(paramValues[i]);
       if(paramValues.length>1)
       allParameter.append(",");
       }
    count++;
  }
```

It works but it seems too complicated (compared with getQueryString) for the works to do.

Is there a better/faster way?

Answer (score 2):

All HTTP (and application servers) support access.log - the log file that stores the HTTP requests and responses details. Just configure it.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this:

```
Enumeration parms = request.getHeaderNames();
String parmname;
String parmval;
while (parms.hasMoreElements()) {
    parmname = (String)parms.nextElement();
    parmval = request.getHeader(parmname);
    Logger.log(parmname + " - " + parmval);
}
```